# Using XPath in C# for get all the node values from XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, .net-2.0

I have got XML below:

```
<tcm:Component ID="tcm:481-636667" IsEditable="false" xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <tcm:Context>
    <tcm:Publication xlink:type="simple" xlink:title="07 Internal Test Publication" xlink:href="tcm:0-481-1"/>
    <tcm:OrganizationalItem xlink:type="simple" xlink:title="System Resources" xlink:href="tcm:481-92640-2"/>
  </tcm:Context> 
  <tcm:Data>
    <tcm:Title>IBE - Skywards</tcm:Title>
    <tcm:Type>Normal</tcm:Type>
    <tcm:Schema xlink:type="simple" xlink:title="Resources" xlink:href="tcm:481-190471-8"/>
    <tcm:Content>
      <Resources xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/tridion/schemas">
        <Text>
          <Key>SKYRL_MBD</Key>
          <Value>Miles Breakdown</Value>
        </Text>
        <Text>
          <Key>ltSR_MB.Text</Key>
          <Value>View Miles Breakdown</Value>
        </Text>
        <Text>
          <Key>ltSR_HMB.Text</Key>
          <Value>Hide Miles Breakdown</Value>
        </Text>
        <Text>
          <Key>SKYRL_MBD_LK</Key>
          <Value>Miles Breakdown</Value>
        </Text>    
      </Resources>
    </tcm:Content>
    <tcm:Metadata>
      <Metadata xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/tridion/schemas">
        <Language>
          <Language>English</Language>
        </Language>
      </Metadata>
    </tcm:Metadata>  
  </tcm:Data>
</tcm:Component>
```

Now I want to write a method in C# which will take this XML as input and will return all the "Key" and "Value" data in List.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, declare the lists to keep values:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

List<string> keysList = new List<string>();
List<string> valuesList = new List<string>();
```

Then:

```
using System.Xml; // System.Xml.dll

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml); // Load(file)

var ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("tcm", "http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0");
ns.AddNamespace("xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");

foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()=\"Key\"]"))
{
    keysList.Add(node.InnerText);
}
foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()=\"Value\"]"))
{
    valuesList.Add(node.InnerText);
}
```

---

if you don't need XML DOM, only XPath to evaluate:

```
using System.Xml.XPath; // System.Xml.dll

XPathDocument doc = null;
using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    doc = new XPathDocument(reader); // specify just path to file if you have such one
}
XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
foreach (XPathNavigator node in (XPathNodeIterator)nav.Evaluate("//*[local-name()=\"Key\"]"))
{
     keysList.Add(node.Value);
}
foreach (XPathNavigator node in (XPathNodeIterator)nav.Evaluate("//*[local-name()=\"Value\"]"))
{
     valuesList.Add(node.Value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aba!!, I am using .NET 2.0, is the above code will work in it also and also after this I need to add all the values in a list also

Comment: I think we cannot use VAR in .NET 2.0, please suggest!

Comment: @Manu: Just indicate the type on both sides. I updated my answer.

Comment: Its giving error on keysList.Add(node.InnerText);
Saying "Innertext" is not defined as well as can you please suggest what type of value will be "XML" in StringReader(xml)

Comment: @Manu: `XPathNavigator.Value` should be used instead. `xml` is a string. If you have file path, use `new XPathDocument(path)`

Comment: @Aba, did you checked this in your editor as I have namespaces in my xml, I think there is different way to work with namespace

Comment: @Manu: You can don't add namespaces but use modified XPath: `doc.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()='Key']")`

Answer (score 3):

Use XElement or XDocument ( Linq2Xml )

```
XElement xml = XElement.Parse("inputxml");
var keys = xml.Descendants("Key");
```

OP says he uses .Net 2.0. Then this won't work!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the classes in the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace.  If you start with an `XDocument` you can load your XML and just query the contents using Linq.

Comment: they may be using .net 2.0 in which case he can't use linq.