# XML get specific name

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have this example of an XML

```
<work>
 <worker name="Jason" job="admin">
 <worker name="Frank" job="employee">
 <worker name="John" job="admin">
<work>
```

I'm trying to retrieve the workers name with the job admin.

Here is a part of my current code. This code will retrieve all workers.

```
Worker = workerElement.Elements("work")
                      .Elements("worker")
                      .Select(c => (string)c.Attribute("name"))
                      .ToArray();
```

I have been trying out the following solution

```
Worker = workerElement.Elements("work")
                      .Elements("worker")
                      .Select(c => (string)c.Attribute("name[@job='admin']"))
                      .ToArray();
```

I want to retrieve all names where the job "title" equals admin.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885795/select-element-with-given-attribute-using-linq-to-xml

Comment: I would recommend at XPath to properly manipulate and navigate XML data. [Here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5946327/82682) from SO.

Comment: None of the tags are closed in your xml...

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I'm not sure that's a valid edit. It fundamentally changes the data-set that the OP is dealing with, and should probably be rolled-back until the OP has some input on that.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I believe it's valid, otherwise it is not xml and cannot be parsed by XElement. OP uses linq to xml, so there is no problems with parsing

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I agree that it's probably what was intended, but by changing the content of the post so radically, you may have solved his only issue, thus making answers irrelevant.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

Solution of @Xtian is correct. Here is XPath solution:

```
var workers = workerElement.XPathSelectElements("//worker[@job='admin']")
                           .Select(w => (string)w.Attribute("name"));
```

Comment: +1 I often use XPath - in many cases I find various selects can be written more clearly with it.

Comment: @pst I wish way for selecting attribute values will be added to XPath. Then all query will be in one line :)

Comment: Fear not, [XPathEvaluate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341675.aspx) can be pretty darn great! (Although, I only find myself occasionally using that - usually when the attributes are part of some automated path.)

Comment: @pst but as I understand it still selects nodes. Something like `((IEnumerable)xdoc.XPathEvaluate("//worker[@job='admin']/@name")).Cast<XAttribute>()`. Is there possibility to select values without casting to XAttributes and projecting results later?

Comment: With `value(..)`. Limited return types, though.

Answer (score 1):

First of all there are a few mistakes on your xml, I've corrected it below:

```
<work>
 <worker name="Jason" job="admin" />
 <worker name="Frank" job="employee" />
 <worker name="John" job="admin" />
</work>
```

Then if you're trying with Linq, try using this:

```
Worker = workerElement.Elements("work")
                      .Elements("worker")
                      .Where(c => (string)c.Attribute("job") == "admin")
                      .Select(c => (string)c.Attribute("name"))
                      .ToArray();
```

Or if you're using XPath you can use:

```
var admins = workerElement.XPathSelectElements("//worker[@job='admin']")
             .Select(w => (string)w.Attribute("name"));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Have been trying something similar to that.